# Media queries not working below min-width 768px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have set some media queries, but some work and some dont. I really dont know what is wrong, because i used the same media query code for another project and that worked as usual. It works from 768px and on but not on smaller screens. I am using bootstrap and angular.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {
   .accordion-ticket {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 481px){
    .accordion-ticket {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
   .accordion-ticket {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Meta tag is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: To bad thats not it.. and it shouldnt make any difference I think, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Offhand I'd say you were missing a `max-width` statement from the middle media query but it's not entirely clear what the issue is.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c2k6xbwx/4/)

```css
.accordion-ticket {
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .accordion-ticket {
    background: blue;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .accordion-ticket {
    background: green;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .accordion-ticket {
    background: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-ticket"></div>
```

Comment: To bad thats not it.. and it shouldnt make any difference I think, thanks anyway

Comment: Then we need a demo of the actual problem

Comment: Just fixed it.. Stupid me! I didnt close a comment right so that caused the error. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your queries are upside down for a start you should have them from the widest to shortest top to bottom.